# How to call a method in another class when the given classname is string

Tags: java, class, object, methods, dynamic

I have two classes in java. I am calling a method of 2nd class from 1st class when the 2nd class name is stored in a string variable.
I tried the below code.It creates the class.

```
String adapterClass = "com.appzillon.server.impl.ViewAccDtlsAdapterImpl";
Class className = Class.forName(adapterClass);
```

After that how to call the method.Method name is `getInfo` with a string type paramater.

Answer (score 1):

```
Method method = className.getDeclaredMethod("getInfo", String.class);
method.invoke(instance, "your parameter");
```

Where `instance` is either:

```
Object instance = null;
```

if the method is static. Or:

```
Object instance = className.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```

If the method is a member method

Comment: Getting the below error on instance declaration line.                                                             Multiple markers at this line
 - Unhandled exception type 
  NoSuchMethodException
 - Unhandled exception type 
  InvocationTargetException
 - Unhandled exception type InstantiationException
 - Unhandled exception type IllegalAccessException

Comment: @VinodhaSamiraja you have to `try-catch` these exceptions or use the `throws` declaration on method level

Answer (score 0):

For scenarios like these, you can very well use Java Reflection APIs. 
`Class classInstance = Class.forName(<your class name>);
 Methoed methodHandle = classInstance.getMethod(<methodName>,<arguments classes>);
Object returnValue = methodHandle.invoke(null, "parameter-value1");`

Note : The null parameter is the object you want to invoke the method on. If the method is static you supply null instead of an object instance